# What is a Spaceman Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a ***Spaceman Word™***.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Spaceman Words™ | Not Spaceman Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| FAMILY | FRIENDS |
| TABARD | TUNIC |
| TAIPAN | MOGUL |
| CLAVUS | CALLUS |
| CEILIDH | SHINDIG |
| REMORSE | REGRET |
| DEMOLISH | ESTABLISH |
| COBALAMIN | RIBOFLAVIN |
| REBUKABLE | COMMENDABLE |
| UNREBUKED | DISCIPLINED |

In case you want it in CSV:

```
Spaceman Words™,Not Spaceman Words™
FAMILY,FRIENDS
TABARD,TUNIC
TAIPAN,MOGUL
CLAVUS,CALLUS
CEILIDH,SHINDIG
REMORSE,REGRET
DEMOLISH,ESTABLISH
COBALAMIN,RIBOFLAVIN
REBUKABLE,COMMENDABLE
UNREBUKED,DISCIPLINED
```

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Spaceman Word™ without relying on the other words.
These are not the only examples of Spaceman Words™; many more exist.

> **What is the special rule these words conform to?**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A Spaceman Word™

> contains a national capital spelled backwards. This is hinted by the fact that SPACEMAN spelled backwards is NAMECAPS i.e. "names of capitals."

The listed examples include

> FAMILY $ \rightarrow $ F **(LIMA)<** Y (capital of Peru)
>  TABARD $ \rightarrow $ **(RABAT)<** D (capital of Morocco)
>  TAIPAN $ \rightarrow $ T **(APIA)<** N (capital of Samoa)
>  CLAVUS $ \rightarrow $ CL **(SUVA)<** (capital of Fiji)
>  CEILIDH $ \rightarrow $ CE **(DILI)<** H (capital of East Timor)
>  REMORSE $ \rightarrow $ R **(ROME)<** SE (capital of Italy)
>  DEMOLISH $ \rightarrow $ D **(LOME)<** ISH (capital of Togo)
>  COBALAMIN $ \rightarrow $ C **(MALABO)<** IN (capital of Equatorial Guinea)
>  REBUKABLE $ \rightarrow $ REB **(BAKU)<** LE (capital of Azerbaijan)
>  UNREBUKED $ \rightarrow $ U **(BERN)<** UKED (capital of Switzerland)

Comment: A perfect answer - well done! Checkmark incoming...